# can not login tuleap after installation, kindly assist

Tags: tuleap

I installed Tuleap appliance installation. stared virtual server. can open http://192.168.42.249 but as I go on Login page, page not found. With messege "The server at sample321.com can't be found because the DNS look-up failed". Kindly suggest a way

Answer (score 0):

It means that you typed "sample321.com" when asked for a domain name at install time but you don't own this domain name.

To solve this you can either:

- Modify your "hosts" file to make sample321.com resolved to 192.168.42.249 (it will only work for you)
- Re-install and enter the VM ip address when asked for a domain name
- Re-install and select a domain name you own and then modify you DNS entry to resolve it to the VM ip address (but this is not viable with a private network 192.168.X.Y)